# SQL name value with highest value in another column

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group, dashdb

let's say I have a table like so:

```
Store    | Item   | Price  
store01  | Apple  | 2.50  
store01  | Pear   | 3.00
store01  | Banana | 3.11  
store02  | Apple  | 2.50  
store02  | Pear   | 2.00
store03  | Banana | 3.10
```

and I just want a query that lists all the stores and names the most expensive item in that store. So I need something like this:

```
Store   | Item  
store01 | Banana 
store02 | Apple 
store03 | Banana
```

I tried something like so:

```
SELECT "Store",
       (case when (max ("Price") = "Price") then "Item" end) as  "Max price Item"   
FROM Table 
group by "Price","Item","Store";
```

but the result of that is just:

```
Store   | Max price Item 
store01 | Apple 
store01 | Pear
store01 | Banana
store02 | Apple
store02 | Pear
store03 | Banana
```

I am running on dashDB.

Comment: Does DashDB support window functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
 SELECT Store, MAX(Price) FROM Table
 GROUP BY Store
```

Or

```
 SELECT
  b.Store,
  MAX(b.Price) as MaxPrice,
  MAX(b.Item) as Item
FROM Table b
INNER JOIN (SELECT 
              Store,
              MAX(Price) as MaxPrice
            FROM Table
            GROUP BY Store) a ON 
a.Store = b.Store AND a.MaxPrice = b.Price
GROUP BY b.Store
```

Sample inputs and outputs:

[image: sample_input]

[image: sample_output]

Comment: Hi, I don't want the max(Price) ... I want the name of the item with the max price

Comment: Updated. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

You should use this

```
SELECT t.Store,
    t.Item
FROM Table t
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT
        Store,
        MAX(Price) AS max_price
    FROM
        Table 
    GROUP BY 
        Store
    ) mt
ON 
    mt.Store = t.Store
    AND mt.max_price = t.Price;
```

Or other way could be:

```
SELECT t.Store,
    t.Item
FROM Table t
WHERE (Store, Price) IN
    (SELECT
        Store,
        MAX(Price) AS max_price
    FROM
        Table 
    GROUP BY 
        Store
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below query

```
SELECT Store,Item
  FROM YourTable T,
        (SELECT Store,max(Price) MPrice
         FROM YourTable
          GROUP BY Store
         ) AS T1
  WHERE T1.Store=T2.Store AND T1.Price=T2.MPrice
```